# Can casperjs set default browsing language, change the website detect geo ip location

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am using casperjs, want to get some information from yahoo.com.us/google.com.us;

however, my ip is in HK, so it automatically change the page to yahoo.com.hk/google.com.hk;

so is there any way to set the default language feedback is EN? here is what i try by changing header:

```
casper.start();
casper.then(function (){
    this.open('http://www.yahoo.com', {
        headers: {
            'Accept-Language': 'en'
}
});
});
casper.then(function (){
    this.echo(this.getTitle()); 
})
```

and the reply is yahoohk, is there any way to get yahoous? (without changing the url)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
'Accept-Language': 'en-US'
```

try US proxy

you can also try this:

```
casper.then(function (){
    casper.page.customHeaders = {
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US'
    };
    this.echo(this.getTitle()); 
})
```

// this will work for sure

```
casper.on('started', function () {
    this.page.customHeaders = { 'Accept-Language': 'en-US' }
});
```